# Что делают функции log, log1p, log10?

Tags: java, функции, математика

В школе мы еще не проходили логарифмы, а при изучении класса `Math`  у меня возникли трудности.
Прочитал про них в интернете, понял что логарифм - степень, в которую надо возвести основание, чтобы получить исходное число.
Словом, логарифм по основанию 2 от 64, например, равен 6: 
log<sub>2</sub>64 = 6

И тут у меня возникли сомнения - в классе `math` есть функция `log`, `log1p`, `log10`

```
Sout(log(10)) = 2.302585092994046
```

Как получено это число? Я так понял:
Cтепень **2.302585092994046**
Число **10**

А основание? И что делают функции **log1p**, **log10**?

Comment: В документации Math вроде должно быть всё написано

Answer (score 14, accepted):

В математике есть такое очень ценное - не менее чем "пи" - число e = 2.718281828459045..., играющее очень важную роль в математическом анализе.

И логарифм по основанию этого *e* так важен, что даже называется *натуральным* логарифмом - и именно он вычисляется функцией `log` (хотя в математике общепринятое обозначение - `ln`).

`log10` вычисляет логарифм по основанию 10.

Вычислить логарифм по одному основанию, зная логарифм по другому, очень просто - вот их основные свойства:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5):

В вопросе есть ещё упоминание о функции log1p. Она просто вычисляет натуральный логарифм от аргумента+1. То есть log1p(x) == log(1+x). Эта функция работает лучше для чисел близких к нулю.

P.S. Выученная таблица десятичных логарифмов от 1 до 10 в третьем классе очень помогает делать быстрые расчеты в уме. То же 2 в 64 сколько? log10(2) * 64 = 0.3010 * 64 = 19.264. Значит это чуть меньше чем 2 на 10 в 19. (по факту - 1.8*10 в 19)

Comment: http://lib.ru/ANEKDOTY/FEINMAN/feinman.txt_with-big-pictures.html#33