# Как решить показательное уравнение?

Tags: c, математика

Попытался решить уравнение 2<sup>2x</sup>=392 средствами языка C. Программа работает, но выдаёт 0, что вроде бы не верно, т.к. 2 <sup>2 * 0</sup> = 1, а 392 != 1.

Код программы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>

main()
{
    float x;
    int power=pow(2,2*x);
    power=392;
    printf("x = %f\n", x);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Это так не работает, запись `power=pow(2,2*x)` вычисляет выражение и пихает его в переменную power **прямо на этом месте** без каких-либо откладываний на будущее. А на этом месте переменная `x` имеет некое неопределённое значение — в вашем случае это оказался ноль. Поэтому вычисляется `power=pow(2,2*0)`, то есть `power` станет единицей. Дальше по ходу программы вы нигде не меняете `x` (поэтому и выводится неизменённый ноль), а `power` вы затираете значением 392 — в итоге выражение `power=pow(2,2*x)` вообще бесполезно ничего не делает. Вероятно, компилятор его вообще выкидывает из программы.

Comment: Спасибо. Но как же тогда найти x?

Comment: @ОлегОстапчук а как вы решаете такие примеры на бумаге? ровно тем же способом это делается и в программах

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков В том то и дело, что не знаю, как этот пример на бумаге решить... По идее, надо 392 представить в виде двойки в степени, но не выходит.

Comment: Попробуйте спросить у гугла, как решать "показательные уравнения", я думаю он вам хорошо обьяснит алгоритм школьной задачи.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков По идее, надо 392 представить в виде двойки в степени, но не выходит. P.S. Сейчас ещё одно пересмотрю, но сомневаюсь, чтоб там новый метод был.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Ладно, пишут, логарифм на то есть)

Comment: А так будет проще? 
2^2x=7^2*2^3, станет понятно что тут надо решать не перебором?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/872655/195342

Answer (score 3):

@Sergey, это неспортивно :)

Хотя бы так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double func(double x)
{
    return pow(2.0,2.0*x)-392;
}

double binEqu(double a, double b, double eps, double (*f)(double))
{
    double x, fa;
    fa = f(a);
    do {
        if (f(x = (a+b)/2.)*fa<0.) b = x; else a = x;
    } while( b-a >= eps );
    return x;
};

int main()
{
    printf("x = %lf\n",binEqu(0.0,100.0,1e-6,func));
}
```

[Мечтательно] Жаль, что тэг не C++, там бы было можно такого навернуть...

Comment: *Жаль, что тэг не C++, там бы было можно такого навернуть...* - особенно, если ещё шаблоны прикрутить... :-)

Comment: @Sergey "О, мсье понимает толк в извращениях!" (с) Анекдот

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

   double x;

// Исходное уравнение:
// pow(2.0, 2 * x) = 392.0
// Прологарифмируем правую и левую части уравнения:
// 2 * x = log2(392.0)
// Разделим на 2.0 правую и левую части:

   x = log2(392.0) / 2.0;
   printf("Корень уравнения: %f\n", x);
}
```